# Counting consecutive letters in java using JOptionPane?

Tags: java

I'm trying to count consecutive letters in java using `JOptionPane` and when I try to compile and run my code I get this:

```
exception in thread main java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
```

I feel like I have most of it down so I'm not exactly sure what's wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string...");

        while (true) {

            if (input.equals("Stop")) System.exit(0);

            else {
                int count = 0;
                int len = input.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i + 1)) count++;
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " +
                    count + "pairs of consecutive letters.");

                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter a string...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i+1` is causing the exception, you need to iterate up to last but one char `for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is:

```
input.charAt(i + 1)
```

This will throw an error because when you are at the last element of the array it will try and get the next element but there isn't one.  Consider revising your logic slightly.

In your for loop you could do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: before the edit you made your comment helped me figure it out. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `JOptionPane` has absolutely nothin to do with that, you should fix your title. The problem is here :

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i + 1)) count++;
}
```

replace that piece of code with

```
for (int i = 0; i < len - 1 ; i++) {
    if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i + 1)) count++;
}
```

This is a basic error, it is important for an efficient programer to be able to deal with this alone and quickly.

Comment: yea i just figured it out as soon as the person made the comment above me. thanks though i'm still learning.